# Scrapy shell doesn't crawl web page

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to use Scrapy shell to try and figure out the selectors for zone-h.org. I run `scrapy shell 'webpage'` afterwards I tried to view the content to be sure that it is downloaded. But all I can see is a dash icon (-). It doesn't download the page. I tried to enter the website to check if my connection to the website is somehow blocked, but it was reachable. I tried setting user agent to something more generic like chrome but no luck there either. The website is blocking me somehow but I don't know how can I bypass it. I digged through the the website if they block crawling and it doesn't say it is forbidden to crawl it. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is cookie issue with you spider, if you send your cookies with your request then you will get you desired data.

You can see that in attached picture.
[image: request with cookie]

Comment: I am not sure how can I check if it is rendered through js also not sure how to change which headers and how.

Comment: view page source of your webpage in any browser by right click and select `view page source`, then find your particular data..

Comment: How come does this clarify this webpage is JS rendered? That just shows me the HTML source of the web page. But Scrapy doesn't get any HTML at all. I didn't understand how your comment solves figuring out the rendering method or changing headers?

Comment: @AaronClifton This Page source is without any rendered java. so if you find your data in this source than it must exist in the scrap's response :) its just a way to find out data exist or being rendered by JS.

Comment: In that case, yes it is there but I can't see it in Scrapy.

Comment: Whats the status of response ?
There must be a misunderstanding.

Comment: This is the response status: `[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.zone-h.org/archive/special=1> (referer: None)`

Comment: How can I send the cookie along with my request?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `scrapy shell "webpage"` on another webpage that you know works/doesn't block scraping?

Have you tried using the `view(response)` command to open up what scrapy sees in a web browser?

When you go to the webpage using a normal browser, are you redirected to another, final homepage?
- if so, try using the final homepage's URL in your scrapy shell command

Do you have firewalls that could interfere with a Python/commandline app from connecting to the internet?

Comment: Yes shell works just fine with other webpages.

view(response) works fine with other pages as well but not with my desired page.

I also tried to see the page and get the link but that didn't work as well. I doubt there is a way to prevent python shell to reach to a particular pages because others work fine.

Comment: What do you mean:
"I also tried to see the page and get the link but that didn't work as well?"

Comment: I meant I used "final homepage's URL" you specified.